# Laravel: Why composer update changes the username() function of AuthenticatesUsers trait?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want the users login to my site by username not email, which is default option of Laravel. So I set this in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

and modified login form. After running `composer update`, I found out that the Laravel automatically reset this function to the default

```
public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}
```

Why this happens? It prevents me to login and just refreshes the form. It took me a long time to find out what is wrong with my codes.

Comment: you dont edit files in 'vendor' ... you override the method in your controller, which it tells you to do in the docs

Comment: If you modify framework code directly it will revert back on every update. You can just override the method within the controller class directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits are basically small reusable pieces of business logic you can drop into your controllers. like your `LoginController` that expose some handy functions, in this case you'll want to override the function.

> By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you
>   would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your
>   LoginController

```
public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```